# i am getting this error in laravel 8 when sending mail for forget password in user authentication that i was doing using jetstream

Tags: email, laravel-8

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0
> Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t17sm10940193wmi.47 - gsmtp "

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Thank u for your response I have resolved the issue by Changing in mail.php file